# nginx if statement string check for domain

Tags: regex, if-statement, networking, nginx, bots

I'm trying to check a string if it matches a list of domains;however, I get the following error:

```
nginx: [emerg] pcre_compile() failed: nothing to repeat in "("*\.duckduckgo\.com|*\.googlebot\.com|*\.crawl\.yahoo\.net|*\.search\.msn\.com|*\.crawl\.baidu.com")" at "*\.googlebot\.com|*\.crawl\.yahoo\.net|*\.search\.msn\.com|*\.crawl\.baidu.com")"
```

I'm using the following statement:

```
if ($rdns_hostname ~* (*\.duckduckgo\.com|*\.googlebot\.com|*\.crawl\.yahoo\.net|*\.search\.msn\.com|*\.crawl\.baidu.com)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using this as your pattern instead: `.*\.duckduckgo\.com|.*\.googlebot\.com|.*\.crawl\.yahoo\.net|.*\.search\.msn\.com|.*\.crawl\.baidu.com`

With regular expressions, `*` matches any number (including none) of the preceding element, which in this case is `.`. A `.` will match any single character, which is why you're escaping the periods in the URL with a backslash, so that they are interpreted as a literal `.` instead of matching any character.